# Entity Framework Core ObjectContext.Refresh equivalence

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, refresh, dbcontext

With Entity Framework 6, it was possible to refresh all the context with the method : **_myObjectContext.RefreshAsync(RefreshMode.StoreWins, GetAll())**

I would like to do the same thing with Entity Framework Core, but I can't find the best way to do that.

So, what's the best way to refresh all the context with EF Core?

Comment: Is this useful for you https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1203?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't currently an equivalent in EF Core. `context.Entry(foo).Reload()` is currently the closest thing, but it only works on a single entity.

In general, we recommend using short-lived contexts that cover a single unit-of-work. This usually makes reloading from the store unnecessary.

You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11706).